# Triggers -- The specified event type(s) is/are not valid on the specified target object

Tags: .net, triggers, sql-server-express

I'm trying to learn about triggers. I'm trying to create a DDL Trigger by creating a new query

```
create trigger triggername
on quickdb
for create_table
as 
begin
print 'new table created'
end
```

but I keep getting

> The specified event type(s) is/are not valid on the specified target object

Comment: What does .Net has to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't write the database name in the `ON` clause of a DDL trigger, you specify if it's on the database level or on the server level.
If it's on the database level, it will only apply to the database it was created in.
Change your code to this:

```
use quickdb
go

create trigger triggername
on database
for create_table
as 
begin
    print 'new table created'
end
```

Comment: Thanks... where can i view the printed message? Also i cannot find the trigger in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You should be able to see it if you run a create table statement using SSMS. Prints in triggers are usually only good for debugging purposes. You should be able to find the trigger in SSMS under Programmability -> Database Triggers.

Comment: Thanks... but i cannot find `Programmability` where is it located ?  https://imgur.com/a/KFKzXqw

Comment: Try refreshing the object explorer. I've just tested and I see my test trigger where it's supposed to be.

Comment: I cannot find the print statement in the `Output` on creation of a new table.. where can i view the print message output?

Comment: In the messages tab

Comment: sorry.. but how to open messages tab? i have created a new table and hit `ctrl+s`..There is no result displayed..

Comment: If you use a create table statement instead of the visual editor you see it.